# how to make nodemon use "scripts" rather than "main" in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, package.json, nodemon

I wrote a simple server with main file named `server.js` so that I have `"main"` field in package.js like this

```
"main": "server.js"
```

My server use some ES7 features so that I run it thrue the babel like this `babel-node server.js`. To prevent typing this command every time when I run the server I've added the `"scripts"` field to package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node server.js",
},
```

after that I can run the server by simply typing `npm start`

I also installed `nodemon` globally to automaticaly restart the server when some changes happen, and I've run into some issue here. When I type `nodemon` in my terminal it tries to run `server.js` without `babel` so that it crashes. If I delete the `"main"` field from package.json nodemon succeed with `"start"` script. So the question is: Can I make `nodemon` use `"scripts"` rather then `"main"` in my package.json, to leave the "main" field as is with nodemon working?

Comment: Can't you run it like `nodemon --exec "babel-node" server.js`?

Comment: Yes, it works. I just want to have less typing. Thats why I'am seeking for some hack at package.json better then deleting "main" property, like may be I can make some nodemon tuning in pachage.json